# How to implement Urban Airship with Phonegap InAppPurchaseManager plugin

Tags: phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

Is anyone familiar with how to implement Urban Airships IAP to the Phonegap InAppPurchaseManager plugin? The reason I am asking is because I am selling magazines and want to be able to download them to my free app instead of having to always update my app, which in turn also gets bigger with each added issue.

Thanks in Advance!